# What word describes a table onto which all others are joined?

Tags: database, data-modeling, terminology

Say I have the following tables:

1. REQUEST
2. DELIVERY
3. PAYMENT

Business process: Customer submits a REQUEST, upon which delivery of the requested item is arranged. Once the item has been DELIVERED, a PAYMENT is processed.

Data flows 1>2>3. If you are working with 2 and 3, some data from 1 will always be logically joinable. I imagine REQUEST to be the spine of the data model, like the spine of a book, holding everything together. What is the correct term for such a table?

Comment: In ORM lingo, the `REQUEST` table might be called the "root" entity/table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while "reasonable" terms for the concept might be possible, you'll have to invent them and they would be idiosyncratic, because there is no commonly accepted term for this.  Qualifications such as "core", "central", "base", ... might do the job if you want to express the idea but that's just about it.